# Adding ActivityIndicator to my application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have got the following code. I a=have added an image in a folder called images. But the message box doesn't pop out.

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                   title: 'Message',
                                   msg: '<img src="/images/spinner.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Wait a minute.',
                                   closable: false
                                   });
```

THe background should be transparent, as just as MBProgressHud. How could i get this to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted three simple mistakes in your code.
For me, this works fine:

```
Ext.**Msg**.show({
                         title: 'Message',
                         **message**: '<img src="**images**/spinner.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Wait a minute.',
                         closable: false
});
```

To sum up, use:

- Ext.Msg.show instead of Ext.MessageBox.show
- 'message' property instead of 'msg' property
- src="images/spinner.gif" instead of src="/images/spinner.gif"

Comment: How do i remove/hide it from the screen ?

Comment: Also, how can i make the background of the MsgBox transparent and How to adjust the Width and Height of the MsgBox ?

Comment: 1) I guess you mean remove it programmatically? Otherwise it's just the obvious (the user clicks on the 'Ok' button). Otherwise you just call the Ext.Msg.hide() function. 2) About width and height, use setWidth() and setHeight() methods of Ext.Msg. 3) About the background, redefine the $sheet-bg-color sass variables (note that it will affect all the action sheets and msg boxes in your app)... You should really have the documentation opened at all time, all these infos are right there. the docs are included in ST2 distribution, so you don't even need to be online...

Comment: I have a problem. I am displaying this Progress Hud, to alert the User that the app is downloading some data from the web-service. But as soon as the MessageBox gets displayed the code beyond the MessageBox doesn't get executed, therefore data is not downloaded from the Web-service. How could i make the MessageBox display asynchronously while data is downloaded from the web-service ? (the documentation says its asynchronous but still it don't work) **From Documentation 'Note that the MessageBox is asynchronous**

Comment: I'd be glad to help with this strange behaviour, but you should post this as a new question with code samples... By the way, the 'closable' config you use does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I think i sorted this issue. +1 for all the effort you took to help me out. cheers.